# Migrating All Metadata from Developer Org to Sandbox

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, sandbox, developer-edition

Is there any way to move all org metadata (Objects, Apex classes, VF pages, Aura) from Developer Edition to Sandbox?

I have started my development in Developer Org, Now i have Purchased new Enterprise Edition, Plan to move all metadata to Sand box.

Is there any way, Please guide me in this

Comment: You can use package builder from here: https://cloudtoolkit.co/, then download all metadata via sfdx into an sfdx app (`sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve --retrievetargetdir . -u username  -k package.xml`), then convert (`sfdx force:mdapi:convert --rootdir ./unpackaged`) and then upload all metadata via normal sfdx to your sandbox.

Comment: @zaitsman got the unpackaged ZIP file, TO upload all metadata, we need to do from https://workbench.developerforce.com/ --> Metadata Deploy?

Comment: I guess you can try that, I never did this. I use SFDX and VS code for all of the development so I just unpackaged this to an SFDX project, then you can right click the `default` folder and say 'Deploy source to org' and voila. (Install SF plugin for VS Code for that button to show)

Comment: you mean to say that we need to Authorize to Sandbox org and Deploy that folder?